# Is there a list of "start-up" events for swfs somewhere?

Tags: events, flash

Basically, I'm looking for all the events that happen as a swf is loading, getting starting, playing the first frame, etc. Ideally, I'd like it broken down by flash version....

Answer (score 1):

I ran this code:

```
var events:Array = [
    Event.ACTIVATE,
    Event.ADDED,
    Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,
    Event.CANCEL,
    Event.CHANGE,
    Event.CLEAR,
    Event.CLOSE,
    Event.COMPLETE,
    Event.CONNECT,
    Event.COPY,
    Event.CUT,
    Event.DEACTIVATE,
    Event.ENTER_FRAME,
    Event.EXIT_FRAME,
    Event.FRAME_CONSTRUCTED,
    Event.FULLSCREEN,
    Event.ID3,
    Event.INIT,
    Event.MOUSE_LEAVE,
    Event.OPEN,
    Event.PASTE,
    Event.REMOVED,
    Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE,
    Event.RENDER,
    Event.RESIZE,
    Event.SCROLL,
    Event.SELECT,
    Event.SELECT_ALL,
    Event.SOUND_COMPLETE,
    Event.TAB_CHILDREN_CHANGE,
    Event.TAB_ENABLED_CHANGE,
    Event.TAB_INDEX_CHANGE,
    Event.TEXT_INTERACTION_MODE_CHANGE,
    Event.UNLOAD
];

for each(var i:String in events)
{
    addEventListener(i, _response);
}


function _response(e:Event):void
{
    trace(e.type);
    removeEventListener(e.type, _response);
}
```

And found that a few of the events initially dispatched include:

1. exitFrame
2. activate
3. enterFrame
4. frameConstructed

This only applies to the `MainTimeline`, but you can perform the same test on other automatically initialized entities as well.

Comment: Nice approach. Where'd you get that list of events? Strangely, when I run that in a browser, I only see #1, #3 & #4 -- no "activate".

Comment: Take a look at: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#summaryTableConstant

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of events that happen when the first frame is about to be played: [The MovieClip life cycle](http://blog.johannest.com/2009/05/22/the-movieclip-life-cycle-event-frame_constructed-and-event-exit_frame/)

Other than that, there are Loader specific events before that, if you are loading a swf from another one:
`Event.INIT` when the swf is ready to play. `Event.COMPLETE` when the download is complete.